# how to give the custom message to calendar for required field in Prime-NG

Tags: html, primeng, primeng-calendar

how to give the custom message to calendar for required field in Prime-NG.

If the form is submitted we will get the default message as **Please fill out this field** but can we get the custom message for p-calendar.

[image]

I have tried with

```
<p-calendar [showIcon]="true" required="true" requiredMessage="Please select date.">

<p-calendar [showIcon]="true" required="true "oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please select the Date')"
oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"  />
```

above code works for only input tag not with p-calendar.

How to resolve this issue.

Comment: not able to set the custom message for p-calendar. it'll work for input tag. @devpato

Comment: The information you have provided is not enough! Please tell what type of form you have used? Is it reactive or template driven?

Comment: I'm using template driven forms @SurjeetBhadauriya

Answer (score 2):

A you are using template driven form you have to use ngModel to bind the value.

So make `<p-calendar>` to use `ngModel`.

```
<p-calendar name="calendar" #calendar="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="calendarDate"  
 showTime="showTime" hourFormat="24" [utc]="true" required></p-calendar>
```

And handle require validation when a it is invalid.

```
<div *ngIf="f.submitted && calendar.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
    <div *ngIf="calendar.errors.required">Date is required</div>
</div>
```

### [Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/prime-ng-calendar-g6patm?file=app%2Fcalendar%2Fcalendar.component.html)

Comment: but can we get the custom message like **Please fill out this page** as the image i have uploaded @SurjeetBhadauriya

Answer (score 0):

You need to use formGroup attribute of the p-calendar and assign the value as the name of your form.
For example:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
  <p-calendar formGroup="myForm" [required]="true"></p-calendar>
  <button [disabled]="!myForm.valid" (click)='submitForm()'><Submit</button>
</form>
```

In this manner, your template-driven form validation will be binded with the primeng elements.
Therafter, you can use CSS and logic to display the error message you want to show.